# dc.js filter by row values

Tags: dc.js

I have a dataset similar to below:

[image]

I would like to find total amount of "sea shipment" over "train shipment" and display it with dc.numberDisplay("#");

total sea shipment / total train shipment

Not sure if i need to use custom reduction.

so far i have used below code but it returns 1

```
   ndx = crossfilter(data);
   var all = ndx.groupAll();

var allGroup = all.reduce(
    function (p, v) {
             
        p.total += v.total;      
        p.sea = (v.shipment_type === "sea") ? 0 : p.total ;
        p.train = (v.shipment_type === "train") ? 0 : p.total ;
        p.air = (v.shipment_type === "air") ?0 : p.total ;

        p.sea_over_train = p.sea / p.train;
        return p;
    },
    function (p, v) {
        
        p.total -= v.total;     
        p.sea = (v.shipment_type === "sea") ? 0 : p.total ;
        p.train = (v.shipment_type === "train") ? 0 : p.total ;
        p.air = (v.shipment_type === "air") ?0 : p.total ;

        p.sea_over_train = p.sea / p.train;
        return p;
    },
    function () {
        return {                  
            total: 0,
            sea: 0,
            train :0,
            air:0,
            sea_over_train:0,

        };
    }
);

seaOverTrain
    .group(allGroup)
    .valueAccessor(function (x) { return x.sea_over_train; })
    .formatNumber(d3.format(".3s"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track but

1. You may have your `?:`s reversed
2. You may need to take the total for each category, and
3. Not use the overall total

Let's take this line as an example:

```
    p.sea = (v.shipment_type === "sea") ? 0 : p.total ;
```

This will set `p.sea` to 0 if the `shipment_type` is `"sea"`, and will set it to `p.total` otherwise. You probably want this the other way around.

Also, I think your intention is to keep a running total of sea, train, and air, so you could use `+=` and `-=`, along with `v.total`, to do that.

Currently these variables will take the overall total from `p.total` (which may be why you're getting 1... not sure...)

Putting these ideas together we get:

```
function (p, v) {
         
    p.total += v.total;      
    p.sea += (v.shipment_type === "sea") ? v.total : 0 ;
    p.train += (v.shipment_type === "train") ? v.total : 0 ;
    p.air += (v.shipment_type === "air") ? v.total : 0 ;

    p.sea_over_train = p.sea / p.train;
    return p;
},
function (p, v) {
    
    p.total -= v.total;     
    p.sea -= (v.shipment_type === "sea") ? v.total : 0 ;
    p.train -= (v.shipment_type === "train") ? v.total : 0 ;
    p.air -= (v.shipment_type === "air") ? v.total : 0 ;

    p.sea_over_train = p.sea / p.train;
    return p;
},
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for. Thank you Gordon.